# On Absolutely Continuous Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I would like to know if we can extend the concept of absolute continuity to functions $f:[a,b]\to X$, where $X$ is a topological vector space. I browsed some books on Topological Vector Spaces but can't find the definition of absolutely continuous functions defined on $[a,b]$ and take values on $X$. I would be greatful if someone can provide me a definition (if possible) of absolute continuous function $f:[a,b]\to X$. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general Topological Vector Spaces: no.

There are two definitions of absolute continuity: one is for functions, the other for measures.

> **Definition (AC for functions)**: Let $I$ be an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is said to be *absolutely continuous* if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $(a_k,b_k) = I_k \subset I$, $k \in \{1\ldots n\}$ are pairwise disjoint subintervals of $I$ satisfying
>   $$ \sum_1^n |I_k|  = \sum_1^n |b_k - a_k| < \delta $$
>   then 
>   $$ \sum_1^n |f(b_k) - f(a_k)| < \epsilon.$$

This definition only requires that we can evaluate
$$ \sum_1^n |f(b_k) - f(a_k)| $$
and naturally we can extend this to the case of the codomain being any metric space $(X,d)$ by replacing
$$ \sum_1^n |f(b_k)- f(a_k)| \implies \sum_1^n d(f(b_k),f(a_k)) $$

A general TVS may not even be metrizable, and I don't see how you can have a reasonable generalisation of the notion of absolute continuity if you don't have a reasonable replacement for $\sum_1^n|f(b_k) - f(a_k)|$.

See also [the EOM entry](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Absolute_continuity#Metric_setting).

> **Definition (AC for measures):** Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ be a measure space (in the interval case we usually take $\Omega = [a,b]$, $\mathcal{S},\mu$ corresponding to the Lebesgue measure). A measure $\lambda$ is said to be absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ if every $\mu$-null set is $\lambda$-null.

The usual generalisation of this concept is to the case where $\lambda$ is a [vector measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_measure) (a measure "taking values" in a Banach space). See, e.g., Chapter 29 of Schecter's [HAF](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/ccc/).

Comment: Ong, +1 for you! Very impressive. With the flow of your reasoning, it seems that we can extend the concept if the codomain is a metrizable TVS? Am I right?

Comment: Well, if you ask that the codomain be a metrizable TVS, you need to show that the set of AC functions are independent of the chosen metrization. I am not sure that it is true.

Comment: What do you mean that the set of AC functions are independent of the chosen metrization? Can you please explain.:)

Comment: Say you have two different metrics $d$ and $\delta$ for the space $X$, both of which generate the topology $\tau$ on your TVS $(X,\tau)$. For it to make sense speaking of an absolutely continuous function taking values in a metrizable TVS $(X,\tau)$, you need to show that if a function $f$ is absolutely continuous using the $d$ metric, it must also be absolutely continuous using the $\delta$ metric, and vice versa. Otherwise you are only studying AC functions with metric space targets, and not those with metrizable space targets.

Comment: Thanks. I still have to look (if its true) that the set of AC functions are independent of the chosen metrization.

Comment: Umm... now if $X$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and let $p_1, p_2: X\to \mathbb{R}_+ \cup \{0\}$ be norms on $X$. Then it is a theorem $p_1$ and $p_2$ generate the same topology on $X$ iff the two norms are comparable. So at least in the case of _normable spaces_, if you use the metric induced by the norm, the class of AC functions can be defined independently of the norm chosen.

Comment: This is great. At least I can work on normable TVS.